# Set up as active a parent-link in React-Router Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ecmascript-6, react-router, navbar

I have a Bootstrap Navbar working fine. When I click on a MenuItem it is setted up as 'active'. But I want that, for example, when I go to Home > Status > NewStatus, the MenuItem Home would 'active'. I have my Bootstrap Navbar with this code:

```
import React from 'react';

import MenuNavItem from './MenuNavItem.jsx'

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    return (
        <nav id="idNavMenu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

            {/*<a class="navbar-brand" href="/inicio"><img id="idFotoLogotipo" width="200px" src="./assets/images/cabecera_CE.jpg"/></a>*/}

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.upct.es/"><span id="idTextoLogotipo">UPCT</span></a>

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/inicio' index={true}>Inicio</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/nueva_incidencia'>Nueva Incidencia</MenuNavItem>
                    <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/mis_incidencias'>Mis Incidencias</MenuNavItem>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <MenuNavItem to=''><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir</MenuNavItem>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    );
}
}
```

and a Menu-Wrapper which lets set as active the MenuItem clicked:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, IndexLink, withRouter } from 'react-router'


export default class NavItem extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    const { router, index, to, children, ...props } = this.props;
    let isActive = false;

    if (router.isActive('./', true) && index) {
        isActive = true
    } else {
        isActive = router.isActive(to)
    } 

    const LinkComponent = index ?  IndexLink : Link

    return (
        <li className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
            <LinkComponent to={to} {...props}>{children}</LinkComponent>
        </li>
    );
}
}

NavItem = withRouter(NavItem);
```

In reference to my menu, if I am at `'/alumno/inicio/OTHER-ROUTE'` I want that `'Inicio'` would be `'active'`.Someone does know how could I do this? (the parent MenuItem -defined in my NavBar, in this case, `'Inicio'`- of a route -in this case `'/alumno/inicio/OTHER-ROUTE'` which `'OTHER-ROUTE'` is not defined on my NavBar- setted up as active) Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you have two ways of doing this. One is you can use `window.location.pathname` which returns the current path as a check. So if you are on `/alumno/inicio/OTHER-ROUTE` then `window.location.pathname` will return `/alumno/inicio/OTHER-ROUTE`. If you are on `/alumno/inicio` then `window.location.pathname` will return `/alumno/inicio`. So you can parse the `window.location.pathname` and see if `inicio` is present and then accordingly set as active. The string to be matched can be passed down as a `prop`.

So something like

```
if(window.location.pathname.includes(this.props.matchPattern)){
        isActive = true
}
```

But this is not "computationally correct" as you will have to make changes to ensure the matches are right. So if there is a path like `/alumno/falumno/inicio` it will return true so you will then have to make the condition such that `inicio` should only come after the second `/` and so on and so forth.

The much better way is to just use React Bootstrap - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

There is an `activeClassName` and `activeStyle` props that you can put on the links and they will be active depending upon whether you are on that path (or subpath).

Comment: Thank you a lot! It is working!. When I have more time, I will try React-Bootstrap as you suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @mrinalmech. Today I get this error. What could it be? (I will post it in an aswer due to I can't paste it here, is too long. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @mrinalmech, could you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702957/how-could-i-solve-this-error-in-wrapper-of-navbar and try to help me, please?

Comment: Hi @mrinalmech. Sorry for giving you so much trouble but ... could you stop by and check this out?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810168/navbar-with-react-router-is-failing-when-route-is-or-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `matchPattern` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see URL-OF-REACT
in a (created by Link)
in Link (created by IndexLink)
in IndexLink (created by NavItem)
in li (created by NavItem)
in NavItem (created by withRouter(NavItem))
in withRouter(NavItem) (created by Menu)
in ul (created by Menu)
in div (created by Menu)
in nav (created by Menu)
in Menu (created by TablaMisIncidencias)
in div (created by TablaMisIncidencias)
in TablaMisIncidencias (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router (created by Routes)
in Routes
```

-------EDIT (SOLVED):

I solved it adding matchPattern in: `const { router, index, to, matchPattern, children, ...props } = this.props;`