# How could I solve this error in Wrapper of Navbar with Parent MenuItem Active?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have next problem. If I have two or more routes that have a common part (eg `/hello`; `/hello/1`; `/hello/1/2`;) and I get into: `/hello/1/2/how_are_you` they (all they) are marked as active (due to all routes is included in the route `3rd route(2nd route(1st route(/hello)/1)/2)/how_are_you`), when I just want to be marked as active the corresponding route, his father (`/hello/1/2` -3rd route-). How could I solve this?

This is my Wrapper code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, IndexLink, withRouter } from 'react-router'


export default class MenuNavItem extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    const { router, index, to, children, ...props } = this.props;
    let isActive = false;

    if (router.isActive('./', true) && index) {
        isActive = true;
    } else {
        isActive = router.isActive(to);
    } 

        // THIS LINE IS PRODUCING THE ERROR
        if (window.location.pathname.includes(to)) {
            isActive = true;
        }

    const LinkComponent = index ?  IndexLink : Link;

    return (
        <li className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
            <LinkComponent to={to} {...props}>{children}</LinkComponent>
        </li>
    );
}
}

MenuNavItem= withRouter(MenuNavItem);
```

this is my MenuItem code:

```
/...
<MenuNavItem to='/hello'>Hello</MenuNavItem>
<MenuNavItem to='/hello/1'>Hello1</MenuNavItem>
<MenuNavItem to='/hello/1/2'>Hello12</MenuNavItem>
/...
```

I am on the route: `/hello/1/2/how_are_you` and I want that only set as active the third MenuNavItem (- `/hello/1/2` - that it is his father, not others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I have two problems:

- If I have two or more routes that have a common part and different depth, all they are marked as active. This problem was solved by: @mrinalmech. This is his solution:

  `let currentPath = window.location.pathName`

  `let depth = (currentPath.split("/").length - 1)`

  `let toDepth = (to.split("/").length - 1)`

  `if (currentPath.includes(to) && toDepth === depth-1) {
       isActive = true;
  }`
- If I have two or more routes that have a common part and same depth, all they are marked as active. I solved this adding to @mrinalmech's asnwer this:

  `let father = currentPath.substring(0, currentPath.lastIndexOf("/"));`

  `if (depth-1 === toDepth && father == to) {
      isActive = true;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Store `window.location.pathName` in `currentPath`

```
let currentPath = window.location.pathName
```

Find the depth of the current path. This gives how nested the current path is

```
let depth = (currentPath.split("/").length - 1)
```

Get depth of parent paths

```
let toDepth = (to.split("/").length - 1)
```

Do the same substring comparison and check that the depth of the parent path is one less than the depth of the current path

```
if (currentPath.includes(to) && toDepth === depth-1) {
         isActive = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment!. So it is fixed that when I am inside `/hello/1/2` not marked `/hello/1` nor `/hello` but when I enter a child element (`/hello/1/2/how_are_you`), no MenuItem marked as active (any of the three). EDIT: --- I have tried to delete what you have comment me, including the IF, and neither are selected the other two, so the problem is that this is not working. Never enter into the IF (I did a console.log and never shows). I do not know why.

Comment: EDIT:--- I put this `let depth = (currentPath.split("/").length - 2) ` due to It marks me that depth = 4 and toDepth=2. But it no solve my error. Now yes entry in the if, but ir marks all as active, as earlier

Comment: EDIT:--- Solved. Now the error is when I have an item of the same level. Eg:
  - `/hello` and
  - `/helloo`. When I am on `/helloo/How_are_you`; both are marked as active. How could I solve this?. thank you for all your help.